# Passing a char buffer to function

Tags: c, pointers

I have some problems with a pointer. My idea was to pass a buffer to a function in order to store the return data in this buffer. But, I do not know if it will work.

```
void main()
{
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) *buf);
    memset(buf, 0x00, BUF_SIZE);
    sendCommand(buf);
}

sendCommand(char *buf)
{
    write(fd, "some commands", strlen("some commands"));
    readResponse(buf);
}

readResponse(char *buf)
{
    read(fd, buf, nbytes);
}
```

I know there is no error handling up to now. And some variables are not well defined. It just depends on the passing buffer. Will I see the data that I get in readResponse() in my main function?

Comment: It's `int main(void)`; you are **not** free to declare main as you please.

Comment: Have you tested it ?

Comment: If you are going to do `memset(buf, 0x00, BUF_SIZE);`, you need `char *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);`. Your expression `sizeof(char) *buf` doesn't make sense. Did you mean `BUF_SIZE * sizeof(*buf)`?

Comment: Sidenote: use clear names describing what the function does. `sendCommand` should either just **send** the command, not get the response, or you change the name to something more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, if you pass a pointer as a function argument, the function can modify the pointed-to object.  That is how `scanf()` works, for example.  And so, too, the very same `read()` function you are using, for that matter.

Comment: Don't treat Sizeof as a Function, remove parentheses from =>> sizeof(char).

Comment: @Michi i think `sizeof(char)` is not needed although.

Answer (score 3):

As in `readResponse()` as you read `nbytes` into buffer pointed by `buf` ,so you will get that data in `main` .

Some improvements to be done -

**1.** `void main()` **->** `int main(void)`  or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

**2.** `char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) *buf);` -> `char *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);    // sizeof(char)=1`  or maybe something you desire (not sure though what you want ??)

Note - remember to `free` allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have a remarkable number of significant problems in the code you presented, considering how short it is.  Other answers have addressed those, though, and your question is not actually about any of them:

> Will I see the data I get in readResponse() in my main function?

Yes, provided that argument `buf` is a pointer to an array large enough to accommodate `nbytes` bytes, and that the `read()` call in fact successfully reads any bytes, those bytes will afterward be visible in `main()` via the pointer it passed to `readResponse()`.  More generally, if you pass a pointer as a function argument, the called function may manipulate the pointed-to object, including by modifying those parts of it that are not `const`.  That's how the `read()` function itself is able to store the bytes it reads into your buffer, after all.

Answer (score 0):

This won't do what you think it does:

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) *buf);
```

Did you mean to multiply with `BUF_SIZE`?